# Defining nth element of combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, functions, algorithms

Let's say I have a set = {$1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10$} and I'm interested in the

$C^{10}_3 = \frac{10!}{3!(10-3)!} = \frac{10*9*8*7!}{3!7!} = 10*3*4 = 120$

Now, say

- $1^{st} element = 1, 2, 3$
- $2^{nd} element = 1, 2, 4$
- $3^{rd} element = 1, 2, 5$
- ...
- $8^{th} element = 1, 2, 10$
- $9^{th} element = 1, 3, 4$
- $10^{nd} element = 1, 3, 5$

Is it possible to define a function $f(x)$ where $x$ is the $n^{th}$ number and $f(x)$ returns the correspondent element? I'm trying to develope a function to replace an array with 1 million elements to try and improve performance.

Thanks in adivance.

Comment: Yes, you just defined such a function.  Do you mean is it possible to compute it more efficiently than counting out the combinations?

Comment: Yes. Although this is a mere example, in my real problem I have more than 1 million elements that had been stored (and indexed). Now I need to increment it and I'd probably have to index another million elements. Instead, I'd like a mathematical function to be capable of defining which set correspond to element 129th, for instance.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Enumerating_k-combinations

Comment: Thanks Vadim123, I guess that's what I was looking for. As soon as I manage to understand that, I'll know for sure.

Comment: I can come up with at least two ways: $O(x + n)$ or $O(n \log^3 x)$ (here $n$ is the number of elements in your set). It depends on how big $x$ is compared to $n$.

Comment: N is going to be pretty big. What is the function O?